# Display data as it is written in form in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form field called description where user can provide the description.In the textbox user can enter data.User can enter the data as list or in any format.How do i show the data in the browser as the   input is given in the textbox.

Example: This is my form

[image]

And this is what i get

[image]

I want the data to be displayed in the way it is entered in the form.How do i achieve this?

This is my "description" part of the form

```
  <tr>
    <td>
     <%--<asp:Label ID="lbl_description" Width="120px" Height="30px" runat="server" Text="description "/>--%>
     <asp:TextBox ID="tb_desc" placeholder="description" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="350px" Height="90px"  runat="server" />
    </td>
   </tr>
```

And this is how i have displayed data

```
<div class="pro_middle">
       <h2><asp:Label ID="lbl_pname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("pname")%>' CssClass="p_name" /> </br></h2>
       <asp:Label ID="lbl_pprice" Text="price: Rs." runat="server" CssClass="plbl" /> <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("pprice")%>' CssClass="p_price" /><br />
       <asp:Label ID="lbl_brand" Text="Brand: " runat="server"  CssClass="plbl"/><asp:Label ID="lbl_pbrand" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("pbrand")%>' /><br />
       <asp:Label ID="lbl_date" Text="Updated on: " runat="server"  CssClass="plbl"/><asp:Label ID="lbl_pdate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("pdate")%>' /><br />  
       <asp:Label ID="lbl_desc" Text="desc:" runat="server"  CssClass="plbl"/><asp:Label ID="lbl_desc1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("pdescription")%>' /><br />  
   </div>
```

**EDIT**
Please don't suggest me to add textbox for each field as it is not possible.
i.e.
That is not possible as the field varies according to product and i have 100s products to enter.I mean for movie i have fields such as "actor","actress"..ets and for water purifier i have fields such as "flow rate","dimention","installation","Tank capacity" etc .And for yet another product i have yet other fields.SO its not possible to write single line textbox for each field

Comment: You are talking about the last multi-line-`TextBox`? Why don't you add multiple single line textboxes, one for every property like `Actor` or `Genre`? How do you want to ensure that the user doesn't enter garbage?

Comment: That is not possible as the field varies according to product....and i have 1000s products to enter.I mean for movie i have fields such as "actor","actress"..ets and for water purifier i have fields such as "flow rate","dimention","installation","Tank capacity" etc .And for yet another product i have yet other fields.SO its not possible to write single line textbox for each field.

Comment: But even if the fields vary you could use another approach. Store them in another table `TProperties` which contains a `Description` and a `Value`. Then one product can have `n` dynamic properties (besides the fix like `Category`). Then you have one entity which you can show and which the user can insert/update/delete as desired. It also allows to show them for example in a `GridView`. That approach would be much more robust.

Comment: Sorry to say but I don't think It would be robust.Say one day a new product came and i have to enter that product.So should i again add another field, make its stored procedure and upload my site.And again next time i do the same.Is it really possible? Haven't you use blog..where you can enter the containt and the content are displayed as it is entered.That is what i am looking for.Thanks

Comment: You've lost me there. My approach does not need to add fields (or even stored-procedures etc). It's just a single table with four columns: the PK-column, the description-field like `Genre`, the value-field like `Comedy` and the FK-column to `TProduct`. A new product would not have any dynamic properties until you add them.

Comment: I don't understand.Can you please explain in more detail or provide me resource where i can learn what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use the `<pre>` html tag. Simply replace this:

```
 <asp:Label ID="lbl_desc" Text="desc:" runat="server"  CssClass="plbl"/><asp:Label ID="lbl_desc1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("pdescription")%>' /><br />
```

with this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_desc" Text="desc:" runat="server"  CssClass="plbl"/><pre><asp:Label ID="lbl_desc1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("pdescription")%>' /></pre><br />
```

Or you could replace `Environment.NewLine` with `<br />` and  with `&nbsp;` when you display it:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_desc" Text="desc:" runat="server"  CssClass="plbl"/><asp:Label ID="lbl_desc1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("pdescription").ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />").Replace(" ", "&nbsp;")%>' /><br />
```

Comment: Wow that was amazing..could you help me replace both line break and  white space at the same time.

Comment: See above: `.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />").Replace(" ", "&nbsp;")`. Is this not OK?